# When passing a user created Stack into a method the passed in Stack is changed

Tags: java, methods, stack

I am trying to pass a Stack into a method, and then create a temp duplicate stack and manipulate the duplicate to see if it is sorted or not.  I have tried everything I can think of, however for some reason if I print the stack before running my isSorted method it prints as expected.  If I run the isSorted method and print the passed in stack it is empty.

Please see the below code block:

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack<RailwayCar> parkingArea) {
        Stack<RailwayCar> tempStack = parkingArea;
        boolean isSorted = true;
        while (!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
            int tempValue = tempStack.pop().getSerialNumber();
            if (!tempStack.isEmpty() && tempValue > tempStack.peek().getSerialNumber()) {
                isSorted = false;
            }
        }
        return isSorted;
    }
```

Comment: You are not creating a temp stack. `tempStack` and `parkingArea` point to the exact same object, that's why after the method the original stack is changed. If you want to copy the stack, you need to manually copy each element into the new stack (or use the `clone` method inherited from `Vector`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not copying the stack, but rather creating another pointer to the stack. tempStack and parkingArea both point to the same object. To create a copy, use the .clone() method.

```
Stack<RailwayCar> tempStack = parkingArea.clone();
```

EDIT: If you need to implement the clone-method yourself, its rather simple to do with the help of a third Stack. Along the lines of the following **pseudocode**:

```
clone():
    copy = new Stack;
    helper = new Stack;
    while not this.is_empty():
        helper.put(this.pop());
    while not helper.is_empty():
        item = helper.pop();
        copy.put(item);
        this.put(item);
    return copy;
```

We're reversing the stack and cloning each element when reversing back.

Note that this will create a shallow copy. As in, copy will point to the same items. To get a deeper copy, you'll have to implement item.clone and call the following:

```
copy.put(item.clone())
```

instead of

```
copy.put(item)
```

Comment: I am using a Stack class that I created not the Java built in Stack.  What would be the correct way to do this without getting cast warnings?  If I try to create a method in my stack class to copy I run into the sam problem if I try to add all the Nodes in the stack I want to copy.

Comment: @MrBigglesworth I added a pseudocode explanation of how you can clone a stack. In your case, you may or may not need to implement RailwayCar.clone as well.

Comment: Thank you, I actually did something very close to that.  I created another stack and pushed everything into it and then pushed it back into the original stack checking if it was sorted.

I understand now why it was changing the parkingArea I didint fully understand about it being a reference pointer but after some reading I get it (or at least enough to understand what was going on).

Thank you again for your help I really appreciate it, and hope you have a good afternoon.